# Magento - Add to cart with quantity field on Upsell products

Tags: magento

I'm trying to get my Upsell products, which I use instead of related products on the view.phtml, to work with a Quantity field in front of the Add to cart button. I'am also using AheadWorks Ajax AddToCart Pro 2.5 extension.

Right now, I'am adding the products without quantity fields with this snippet:

```
<form action="<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_link) ?>" method="post" id="view_addtocart_form_<?php echo $_link->getId(); ?>"><button onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_link) ?>')" class="greenbutton" title="Add to Cart" type="button"><span><span>Add to Cart</span></span></button></form>
```

This works great, but I cannot change the quantity due to the lacking quantity field. Then I try to use this from my list.phtml which works fine, in the category view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                    function setQty(id, url) {
                        var qty = document.getElementById('qty_' + id).value;
                        document.getElementById('cart_button_' + id).innerHTML = '<button type="button" class="greenbutton-small" onclick="setLocation(\'' + url + 'qty/' + qty + '/\')"><span><span>Læg i kurv</span></span></button>';   
                    }
                </script>
                <label for="qty"><?php echo $this->__('Qty:') ?></label>
                <input type="text" name="qty_<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>" id="qty_<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>" maxlength="12" value="1" onkeyup="setQty(<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>, '<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>');" title="<?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?>" class="input-text qty" />
                <span id="cart_button_<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>">
                <button type="button" class="greenbutton-small" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button></span>
```

Now, the funny thing is, this does not work if I try to use it in upsell.phtml, but I cannot figure out why? This works perfect with Ajax Cart Pro from AW in the Category view's.

Comment: thanks for posting this question I also have this problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `upsell.phtml` the product object is called `$_link` per the following code:

```
<?php if($_link=$this->getIterableItem()): ?>
```

If you're trying to include your code in your `upsell.phtml` then you'll have to change `$_product` to `$_link` like this:

```
<label for="qty"><?php echo $this->__('Qty:') ?></label>
            <input type="text" name="qty_<?php echo $_link->getId(); ?>" id="qty_<?php echo $_link->getId(); ?>" maxlength="12" value="1" onkeyup="setQty(<?php echo $_link->getId(); ?>, '<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_link) ?>');" title="<?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?>" class="input-text qty" />
            <span id="cart_button_<?php echo $_link->getId(); ?>">
            <button type="button" class="greenbutton-small" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_link) ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button></span>
```

It should go after the following line:

```
<?php if($_link=$this->getIterableItem()): ?>
```

Comment: You deserve a hug.. from somebody hot! ;) hehe. That really saved my day. Thanks alot, such a little thing, didn't even think about it. Thank you very much.

Comment: this answer saved my time